# How to prevent connection break on ESC press?

Tags: javascript, browser, html

When we press ESC, browser's server connection would break unless another request such as user input or ajax request.

My problem is that when I press ESC while I am uploading the file into server, my upload do not process further(It hanged).
But I need to press ESC for some feature of my page. Such as,

1. Pressing ENTER for rename and ESC for ignoring rename.
2. Pressing ESC to cancel the message box, etc.

How do I write JavaScript to prevent the breaking of connection when we press ESC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the Two functions for ignoring rename and canceling message box be
`cancelRename();`  and `cancelMsgBox();`
Now check for ESC press on your browser by this script;

```
function isESCpress(ev) {
if(ev.keyCode==27) {cancelRename();cancelMsgBox();return false;}
}
document.onkeypress=isESCpress;
```

Note:

Function `cancelRename();` and `cancelMsgBox();` will always called when you press ESC. Thus you have to manage that yourself.

Hints:

```
function cancelRename() {
if(cancelStatus==1) //do your rename cancel process
}
```